# Trying to create the distinct of items in Map using Java streams

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

I have a `List<Child>`, which I want to iterate and create a `Map<Long, List<Child>>` by taking the distinct values (**distinct of parent_id**).

Sample data:

```
**Parent table:**
project_id  project_desc
1             One
2             Two

**child table:**
child_id  parent_id  code
1           1         code1
2           1         code2
3           1         code3
4           2         code4
4           2         code5
```

I tried with the below code, but it is throwing the exception

```
List<Child> childEntityList = // initializing the list

Map<Long, List<ChildEntity>> childEntityMap = childEntityList.stream()
    .collect(toMap(
        childEntity ->  childEntity.getParent().getParentId(), 
        childEntity ->  childEntity
    ));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a wrong Collector.

Because you need to associate each *Key* with a **group** of *Values* (**not** with a single value) the right choice would Collector [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)).

You need the flavor of `groupingBy()` which expects only one argument - *classifier* function, which tells how to extract the *key* from the stream element. By default, *values* mapped to the same *key* would be stored into a list.

```
Map<Long, List<Child>> map = childEntityList.stream().
    collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        childEntity ->  childEntity.getParent().getParentId()
    ));
```